# read csv into index of year, dayofyear, and hour/min into a pandas datetime object

Tags: datetime, csv, pandas, julian-date

I am trying to read in a csv in this form:

```
2014,92,1931,6.234,10.14
2014,92,1932,5.823,9.49
2014,92,1933,5.33,7.65
2014,92,1934,4.751,6.19
2014,92,1935,4.156,5.285
2014,92,1936,3.962,4.652
2014,92,1937,3.74,4.314
2014,92,1938,3.325,3.98
2014,92,1939,2.909,3.847
2014,92,1940,2.878,3.164
```

To be clear, this is (Year, Day of year, 2400hr time, and 2 columns of values).

I have had some thought on the matter in a previous question, but to no avail, and it's proving to be a matter of a few problems... ([Create an indexed datetime from date/time info in 3 columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620333/create-an-indexed-datetime-from-date-time-info-in-3-columns-using-pandas))

As noted in the above question, the following "read_csv" attempt

```
df = pd.read_csv("home_prepped.dat", parse_dates={"dt" : [0,1,2]}, 
                  date_parser=parser, header=None)
```

triggers a TypeError:

```
TypeError: parser() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

This is due to the "parse_dates" arg having 0,1,2 in it. 
I have also tried putting them in double brackets [[0,1,2]] and get:

```
ValueError: [0, 1, 2] is not in list
```

I have gotten past this by setting parse_dates=True and thought I could just set_index after but get this:

TypeError: must be string, not numpy.int64

My parser gets hung up on the format too, and I have read conflicting stories about zero-padding the "day of year" value. Mine are not zero-padded, but even still, above errors aside I have had the format get hung up on the first value, the year! Here is the parser:

```
def parser(x):
    return pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %j %H%M')
```

So yea, I have had errors saying '2014' not recognized, and '92' (day of year) not recognized, but have been encouraged cause at least strptime has been able to make its way "through" to try out the format.

I am wondering if this has something to do with my data.

I am looking for a way to get this datetime info indexed as a datetime and I have had nothing but problems. I have gone ahead and padded some julians in case someone wants to test out the format being a problem of the padding, see below:

```
2014,092,1931,6.234,10.14
2014,092,1932,5.823,9.49
2014,092,1933,5.33,7.65
2014,092,1934,4.751,6.19
2014,092,1935,4.156,5.285
2014,092,1936,3.962,4.652
2014,092,1937,3.74,4.314
2014,092,1938,3.325,3.98
2014,092,1939,2.909,3.847
2014,092,1940,2.878,3.164
```

Thanks for your help guys, I am starting to really get frustrated here :S

Answer (score 1):

After correcting your `%m` (month) to `%M` (minute), your code works for me:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print pd.version.version
0.15.2-10-gf7af818
>>> 
>>> def parser(x):
...         return pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %j %H%M')
... 
>>> df = pd.read_csv("home_prepped.dat", parse_dates={"dt" : [0,1,2]}, 
...                  date_parser=parser, header=None)
>>> df
                   dt      3       4
0 2014-04-02 19:31:00  6.234  10.140
1 2014-04-02 19:32:00  5.823   9.490
2 2014-04-02 19:33:00  5.330   7.650
3 2014-04-02 19:34:00  4.751   6.190
4 2014-04-02 19:35:00  4.156   5.285
5 2014-04-02 19:36:00  3.962   4.652
6 2014-04-02 19:37:00  3.740   4.314
7 2014-04-02 19:38:00  3.325   3.980
8 2014-04-02 19:39:00  2.909   3.847
9 2014-04-02 19:40:00  2.878   3.164
```

But after playing around with this for a little while, there are some very strange behaviours when an error happens, leading to some odd error messages, so I can see why it's very hard to debug this.

---

If for some reason the above isn't working, you could try doing the parsing yourself:

```
df = pd.read_csv("home_prepped.dat", header=None)
timestr = df.iloc[:,:3].astype(str).apply(' '.join,axis=1)
df = df.iloc[:,3:]
times = pd.to_datetime(timestr, format='%Y %j %H%M')
df["dt"] = times
```

As mentioned above, when something goes wrong (e.g. a parse error) the error messages are very confusing from within `read_csv`.

Comment: oh right, monthly typo, thanks; I saw that just after the post actually. Anyway, I appreciate the work on this... I should have mentioned I am running version:In [80]:

pd.__version__
Out[80]:
'0.15.2'

Comment: I've edited to include a very brute-force way of doing it.  If there's something wrong with your data which is causing the problem, then the `times` line may fail.  If so, then you just need to find the troublesome values.

Comment: hey that's great, you really know your stuff. I am more familiar with bash than I am with python. Do you think things would be easier for me if I convert the dates before bringing them into pandas?

Comment: perhaps it is the %j that is messing with it, as it is not really Julian day but rather day of the year.

Comment: I had an idea: do you think I should just manually create the date_range myself and then append the values to the range? If so, I suppose I will have to worry about DST and other shifts

Comment: Up to you.  If you upload the file to one of the temporary sites like [dpaste](http://dpaste.de) I can have a look, but so far I haven't had trouble parsing what you've shown, suggesting that the problem is later in the file.  You can do manual work in bash, but if something is causing problems for `pandas` it's likely going to cause problems for other algorithms too, but silently.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work, i think. Keep in mind this is the first time I have ever brought anything into pandas to work with so not sure how to properly test it, but it recognizes the format and says:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-04-02 19:31:00, ..., 2014-12-21 23:59:00]
Length: 337917, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Which is sweet, as I believe this means I have finally indexed a datetime!

Here is what I did...

```
In [41]:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
In [60]:

def parse(yr, yearday, hrmn):
          date_string = ''.join([yr, yearday, hrmn])
          return datetime.strptime(date_string,"%Y%j%H%M")
In [61]:


df = pd.read_csv('home_prepped.csv', parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1,2]}, date_parser=parse, index_col='datetime', header=None)
```

Now I tried to put a space in between the '' before the .join and it separated the %Y %j but only managed to see a "1" as part of the %H. So I got rid of the space and changed the format to be spaceless as well.

Thanks for your work on this DSM.